# Headers already sent when using MakeGood plugin

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit, makegood

When using the MakeGood plugin in Eclipse to run a test that sets headers, I get:

```
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\pear\PHPUnit\Util\Printer.php:173)
```

This same test works fine when I run it through Phing. I'm assuming that Phing sets output to stderr because when I run the same test from the phpunit command line with the --stderr switch, it works fine. It fails the same way as with MakeGood without the --stderr switch.

Is there a way around this, or a way to set output to stderr in the MakeGood plugin?

Also, this shouldn't make any difference, but this is a Zend Framework project and I've set

```
Zend_Session::$_unitTestEnabled = true;
```

in my testing bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that PHPUnit will print a header to the screen and at that point PHP can't send any more headers.

The work around is to run the test in an isolated process. Here is an example

```
<?php

class FooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @runInSeparateProcess
     */
    public function testBar()
    {
        header('Location : http://foo.com');
    }
}
```

This will result in:

```
$ phpunit FooTest.php
PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.

Time: 1 second, Memory: 9.00Mb

OK (1 test, 0 assertions)
```

The key is the @runInSeparateProcess annotation.

You can also use the --process-isolation flag when running PHPUnit.

If you are writing code around Zend Framework you should not be using header() directly. You should use Zend_Http_Response.

Also if you are doing MVC level testing I suggest you look at [Zend_Test_PHPUnit](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.test.phpunit.html).

Comment: thanks for the response. Unfortunately, using the the `@runInSeparateProcess` annotation and/or the --process-isolation flag cause MakeGood to just sit there doing nothing. The only console output is PHPUnit 3.5.15 by Sebastian Bergmann.. I am actually using Zend_Test_PHPUnit. Not sure what you mean by using Zend_Http_Response. Here's my controller action. public function robotsAction() { header('Content-type: text/plain'); $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout(); }

Comment: Try replacing your call to header() with **$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');**

Comment: Thanks a bunch! MakeGood is happy now, and thanks for the tip about Zend_Http_Response. :)